# C++ expected '{' at end of input

Tags: c++

In this line of my code, I am getting

> [Error] expected '{'

at the end of the input. But as you see, none of the '{}' are incomplete. So what gives?

```
Phone(double phonePrice, bool Iphone, int phoneYear) : Apple{Iphone}, price{phonePrice}, yrs{phoneYear};
```

Comment: Your  `constructor` is missing its body.

Comment: *"none of the '{}' are incomplete"* -- right, but the error for an incomplete pair would mention the **closing** brace. Your error mentions the **opening** brace, which should be viewed as a *missing* '{}'.

Comment: Potential duplicates: [Constructor error: expected ‘{’ at end of input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36749287/) and [expected `{' at end of input when trying do declare constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13324687/)

Answer (score 1):

You missed the `{` and `}` of the body of your constructor:

```c++
Phone(double phonePrice, bool Iphone, int phoneYear)
: Apple{Iphone}, price{phonePrice}, yrs{phoneYear}
{
    // Constructor body
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the body of your `constructor`

```
class Phone : public Apple {
public:
    Phone(double phonePrice, bool Iphone, int phoneYear) 
        : Apple{Iphone}
        , price{phonePrice}
        , yrs{phoneYear}
    { }
private:
    // Private fields.
}
```